# Javascript DIV Display not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a strange issue that I can't seem to figure out.  I've got a simple onclick event that shows/hides a particular div.  It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE but does not work in Safari (desktop or mobile).

HTML CODE:

`<a href="/link.html" onclick="toggleDiv();">`

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv()
{
    document.getElementById("button-group-active").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("button-group").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I don't get any errors in the console or any indication to help me understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You have the href atribute set to  "/link.html", and this should load the link.html

Im not sure why this won't happen in the other browsers, but you could try leaving href blank.

Comment: My issue isn't with the link.  It works just fine.  My issue is with the div toggle.

Comment: Clicking the link will change the page so the javascript will not be run